# Is the set $S=2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the set $S=2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}=\{(2x,y):x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ a ring under the operations of addition defined as $$(2x,y)+(2z,w)=(2x+2z,y+w)$$ and multiplication defined as $$(2x,y)\cdot(2z,w)=(2x\cdot2z,y\cdot w)?$$
I am currently stuck trying to prove it has an identity element under multiplication. The element can't be $(1,1)$, because $(1,1)\notin S$. Is there an element in S that could be the identity element or does it not have one and is, therefore, not a ring?

Comment: If you assume a ring must have an identity then no, this isn't a ring. In general, we can also discuss rings without identity, and this is an example of such a ring.

Comment: If $(a,b)$ were an identity element in $S$, then $(a,b) = (a^n,b^n)$ for all $n$. But $a$ cannot be zero (why?) and $|a| \ge 2$ for all elements in $S$ for which $a \ne 0$. Therefore ....

Comment: More generally, whenever you have any number of rings $(R_i)_{i\in I}$ and define the operations coordinate-wise as you did, the result $R=\prod_{i\in I}R_i$ is also a ring. The same is valid for groups, vector spaces over the same field, semigroups, etc. (But not for fields, for example; fields have a partial operation, the inverse, and that's what makes this construction fail for those structures.)